# From what MySQL index would this query benefit?

Tags: mysql, indexing

**UPDATE:** Added the query that runs second most:

(maybe needed when taking an index in consideration???)

```
SELECT m.time, m.message, m.receiver_uid AS receiver, m.sender_uid AS sender
    FROM messages AS m, users AS u
    WHERE u.uid = '$coID' 
        AND ( (m.receiver_uid = '$meID' AND m.sender_uid = '$coID') OR
              (m.receiver_uid = '$coID' AND m.sender_uid = '$meID') )
    ORDER BY m.time DESC
```

- $meID is the iD of the user who runs the wuery,
- $coID is the ID of the contact.

---

I've got a somewhat big query and it runs everytime an user visits my page.

```
SELECT  m2.message, m2.time, m2.sender_uid AS sender, m2.receiver_uid AS receiver, 
        m.contact, u.ufirstname
FROM (  SELECT  CASE
                WHEN sender_uid = '$me' THEN receiver_uid 
                ELSE sender_uid 
                END AS contact,
                MAX(time) AS maxtime
        FROM messages 
        WHERE sender_uid = '$me' OR receiver_uid = '$me'
        GROUP BY CASE
                 WHEN sender_uid = '$me' THEN receiver_uid 
                 ELSE sender_uid
                 END                                        ) AS m
INNER JOIN messages m2 ON m.maxtime = m2.time
AND ((m2.sender_uid = '$me' AND m2.receiver_uid = m.Contact)
OR (m2.receiver_uid = '$me' AND m2.sender_uid = m.Contact))
INNER JOIN users AS u ON m.contact = u.uid
ORDER BY time DESC
```

- $me is the ID of the user who runs the query

This query will (successfully) retrieve:

```
LAST MESSAGE from EVERY 'CONVERSATION' ordered by TIME.
```

So it will get the last message (whether the message is send or received) in every PM session
And than sort those by time, and retrieves the contacts information.

Please tell me if I didn't explain it correctly.

My MySQL table looks like this:

```
receiver_id | sender_id | message | time
```

**From what index(es) would this query benefit?**

(The user table already has an primary key on the ID so the part where the join retrieves the contacts name should be efficient)

**EXPLAIN OUTPUTs:**

**The BIG query:**

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4   Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY     m2  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    42  Using where
1   PRIMARY     u   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   m.contact   1   Using where
2   DERIVED     messages    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    42  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

**The query in the update part:**

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  u   const   PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   const   1   Using index; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  m   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    42  Using where
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found by trail and error that indexing the time decreases the load time.
So that will probably be the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

As your messages table grows, this query will start becoming slower and slower. Depending on the number of conversations that the user is a part of, you will start seeing exponentially decaying performance. While an individual index on messages.time, messages.sender_uid and messages.receiver_uid will help for now, no index will help you in your long run, unless you trim your messages table. Especially when you have more than a few hundred thousand messages.

I would suggest maintaining an association type type that links a user to a conversation and their last message id. Something looking like:

user_id  |  conversation_id  |  message_id

You then look up this table, instead of performing a complicated and expensive query. This greatly reduces the number of scans that you need to do on your messages table. While, it does slightly increase the complexity, the performance will not degrade as much as your query above.

Comment: What about moving the older (14days) messages to an older table?
So only when the user really want to read the older messages he will have to search in a long table.